# OmniSharp MSBuild ProjectManager is not able to update my .csproj file

Tags: c#, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, .net-core-3.0

Using VS Code 1.38.1, Win10 Build 190921, WSL2, .NET Core 3.0.1 (all refreshed today).  Trying to use the OmniSharp debug extension, here is what I see.

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/jdunn7453/dnc/sample1/sample1.csproj
```

The launch.json file contains

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "WARNING01": "*********************************************************************************",
            "WARNING02": "The C# extension was unable to automatically decode projects in the current",
            "WARNING03": "workspace to create a runnable launch.json file. A template launch.json file has",
            "WARNING04": "been created as a placeholder.",
            "WARNING05": "",
            "WARNING06": "If OmniSharp is currently unable to load your project, you can attempt to resolve",
            "WARNING07": "this by restoring any missing project dependencies (example: run 'dotnet restore')",
            "WARNING08": "and by fixing any reported errors from building the projects in your workspace.",
            "WARNING09": "If this allows OmniSharp to now load your project then --",
            "WARNING10": "  * Delete this file",
            "WARNING11": "  * Open the Visual Studio Code command palette (View->Command Palette)",
            "WARNING12": "  * run the command: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'.",
            "WARNING13": "",
            "WARNING14": "If your project requires a more complex launch configuration, you may wish to delete",
            "WARNING15": "this configuration and pick a different template using the 'Add Configuration...'",
            "WARNING16": "button at the bottom of this file.",
            "WARNING17": "*********************************************************************************",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Revert from 3.0 to 2.2. Omnisharp seems to need a MSBuild that supports dotnet Core 3.0. VS2019 has one, but as you know there is no version of visual studio available to ubuntu yet.